# Ionic - Error during creation of the project (postcss ??)

Tags: npm, ionic4

Someone can help me please, I am trying to use ionic.

I have run

```
sudo npm install -g @ionic/cli
```

Now I am running this command but I have an error

```
ionic start myApp tabs

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Found: postcss@8.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/postcss
npm ERR!   postcss@"8.2.14" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1102.13
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1102.4" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^0.1102.4" from @ionic/angular-toolkit@3.1.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit
npm ERR!       dev @ionic/angular-toolkit@"^3.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer postcss@"^8.1.0" from autoprefixer@10.2.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/autoprefixer
npm ERR!     autoprefixer@"10.2.4" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1102.13
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!       dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1102.4" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (@ionic/angular-toolkit)
npm ERR!   9 more (css-loader, cssnano, postcss-import, postcss-loader, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer postcss@"^8.2.15" from cssnano-preset-default@5.1.1
npm ERR! node_modules/cssnano/node_modules/cssnano-preset-default
npm ERR!   cssnano-preset-default@"^5.0.1" from cssnano@5.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/cssnano
npm ERR!     cssnano@"5.0.2" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1102.13
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!       dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1102.4" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (@ionic/angular-toolkit)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/jonathan/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/jonathan/.npm/_logs/2021-05-21T19_38_40_797Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.
        
        npm i --save -E @capacitor/core@latest exited with exit code 1.
        
        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

I am stuck since a few hours, I do not understand what happens. Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I have found the solution, just running

```
npm install postcss@"^8.2.15"
```

Comment: This also helped me when using Angular.